# navigate in 2D and 3D on the google map

Tags: android

I am trying to develop a location-based application and I have to allow the user to navigate in 2D and 3D on the map. then I'll know how I can display the map in 2D and 3D

Comment: please show your efforts

Comment: I have  integrate the google maps and located the user. but I don't know how to navigate in 2D and 3D. I really search but I don't even found difference betwen 2D AND 3D navigation

Comment: I use Fragment                                                                                                                            Fragment fragment=((com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
   if (fragment != null)
          getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
   map = ((com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment) fragment).getMap();
  
   map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
   marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Vous êtes ici").position(new LatLng(0, 0)));

Answer (score 0):

With the [deprecation of Google Earth API](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.gr/2014/12/announcing-deprecation-of-google-earth.html), it will be hard to achieve a 3D and 2D representation simultaneously. You can check [Niliteq](http://www.nutiteq.com/nutiteq-sdk/overview/) which seems to support both, but it is [not free](https://developer.nutiteq.com/). For 2D mapping, you should go for [GoogleMap v.2 API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/).